# Is there a way to make an executable from an Xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I feel it's quite a naive question I'm going to ask. Excuse me if it's foolish.

I have made an iPhone game using Cocos2d, Box2d and OpenGL. I want to show the game to a potential employer for demonstration purposes, without giving him the source code.

How can I make a .exe or .app file from the Xcode project?

I've searched online a lot but couldn't find the relevant answer.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to give him something to run in the iPhone Simulator, then build the project in Debug mode, look inside the `build/Debug-iphonesimulator/` folder created by the build process and give him that app. If you want him to run the app on his phone/iPod/iPad, then you need to join the iPhone developer profile and follow the provisioning portal instructions.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot :). the .app file was there but it wasn't running directly. So, what I did was to make a new Xcode project, add that .app in the executables (by right-clicking on the 'Executables', going to Add --> New custom executable and choosing that .app file), right-click on the newly added executable and select 'Start executable'. And here it is running fine.
(Just in case someone is looking for the same thing I was).